# Finding and Deleting one line of Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has several modules with multiple sub procedures. One module has the multiple procedures and another module Calls each of those procedures. The problem is that the list of Call Subs will vary. I know how to add to the below routine, but I can't figure out how to delete a line, based off of what I enter in a cell in the worksheet. The process would be to enter "Call TMS1707455" in a cell, then run a macro that would delete the value of that cell from the below sub.

```
Sub TMS()

    Call TMS1707455
    Call TMS1367006
    Call TMS4268798
    Call TMS1366994
    Call TMS39522
    Call TMS39523
    Call TMS4482313
    Call TMS19395
    Call TMS39415
    Call TMS37118
End Sub
```

Or, would it be better or possible to enter this list of Call Subs in a worksheet column. I could then modify the list as needed and have a macro that would call all of the procedures based on the column of call subs. This way, I wouldn't have to have a macro to add lines and a macro to delete lines. I just can't find any info on how to do either ways.

Comment: Are all those subroutines similar? It's a bit of a code smell to see something like that snippet. You can use `Application.Run` for the second scenario.

Comment: Seems to be a XY problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `delete the value of that cell from the below sub`, but you can keep one sub and choose to run any procedure inside it with a `If` or `Case` statement. `If Range("A1").Value = TMS1707455 Then Call TMS1707455`, for example.

Comment: In order to receive an idea on the issue, I think it would be better to tell us what do you want to achieve using that range of calls. According to your need of accomplishing something we maybe can help with ideas...

Comment: @BigBen. The subroutines are similar. Below is a sample of two of them.  <br/>

Sub TMS1707455()
    Cells.Replace What:= _
    "1707455(HSPD-12 Sponsor Certification Training)", _
    Replacement:="HSPD-12 Sponsor Certification Training"
End Sub

Sub TMS1367006()
    Cells.Replace What:= _
        "1367006(VA Telework Training Module For Employees)", _
        Replacement:="VA Telework Training Module For Employees"
End Sub

I split them up to make it easier to delete them when no longer needed. These subs are in one Module, then the other module has all the Call Subs.

Comment: Sounds like you could refactor to have *one* sub that takes a list of terms to find and their corresponding replacements.

Comment: @BigBen.  So, I have a report that I run and I'm trying to make it more readable, that's the reason for the Replace function.  The report is a list of all training items for multiple personnel. When a new training item is added to our requirements, I add a sub to filter out extraneous data so all that's left is just the title of the training. When a training item is no longer required, I want to delete the subroutine.  I know how to delete an entire sub, what I want is to delete the one line Call Sub that corresponds with the Replace function sub.  Sorry, I'm very new to macros.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help you a lot and I think the example demonstrates many programming principles that will help you write more efficient/manageable/editable code moving forward. Note the comments as well.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TMS()

    cleanUp "TMS1707455"
    cleanUp "TMS1367006"
    '... etc
    'add / delete comment as needed

End Sub

Sub cleanUp(which As String)

    Dim findIt As String, changeTo As String

    Select Case which

        Case Is = "TMS1707455"
            findIt = "1707455(HSPD-12 Sponsor Certification Training)": changeTo = "HSPD-12 Sponsor Certification Training"
        Case Is = "TMS1367006"
            findIt = "1367006(VA Telework Training Module For Employees)": changeTo = "VA Telework Training Module For Employees"
        'Case Is = ' ... next in line '
        'delete cases as needed, or comment them out

    End Select

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("mySheet") 'always explicitly declare and work directly with objects

    ws.Cells.Replace What:=findIt, Replacement:=changeTo
    'i would also suggest only working with the cells with actual data you need,
        'like the columnset or row set, it will speed up the code, especially using Replace

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do.  The below code deletes one line of my macro, depending on the value in a cell. I found the answer here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx
It may not be pretty, but it works.

```
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim FindWhat As String
    Dim SL As Long ' start line
    Dim EL As Long ' end line
    Dim SC As Long ' start column
    Dim EC As Long ' end column
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module2")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    FindWhat = [C21]

    With CodeMod
        SL = 7
        EL = .CountOfLines
        SC = 1
        EC = 255
        Found = .Find(target:=FindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
            EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
            wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
        If Found = True Then
            .DeleteLines StartLine:=SL
        End If
    End With
```